# if size == 4,7,10,13, .... so on... in jQuery

Tags: jquery, match, matching, if-statement

I know i can do like this...

```
if (Size == 4 | Size == 7 | Size == 10 | Size == 13 | Size == 16 | Size == 19)
{alert("Yes!")}
```

But any better coding ?

Comment: You should try the [CodeReview SE site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For starters im guessing you actually meant or statements in which case you need to use || not a single |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(Size%3==1&&Size<20&&Size>3 )
{alert("yes");}
```

Comment: Obviously this is if the numbers he chose werent accidently (multiples of 3)+1 :)

Comment: Then this if condition will not run

Comment: so what about if i use only Size%3==1 ?

Comment: but if you want to exceed the limit of size then instead of Size<20 write Size<23 or 26 or 29 ...

Comment: @l2aelba then it will run for all number that leave remainder 1 on division by 3

Comment: if i dont set limitation... its ok ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) :

```
if (jQuery.inArray(Size, [4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19])>=0) {
```

Note that the goal can only be readability, not performances.

If you have only those 6 values and if they never change, the ugly `if` you made (with `||` instead of `|`) is a perfectly correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
switch (Size) {
    case 4:
    case 7:
    case 10:
    case 13:
    case 16:
    case 19:
        alert("Yes!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if((Size - 1)%3 == 0)
     alert("Yes!");
```

Comment: @l2aelba - shortest isn't always the best. Just as important are readability and maintainability, performance, and actually doing what you want (this answer doesn't do the same as the code in the question if Size is smaller than 4 or bigger than 19).

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo

```
if (((Size - 1) % 3) == 0) {
  alert ("yess!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put those numbers in a array and than use

```
if(JQuery.inArray(Size, [4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19])>=0)
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

But this make only the code look "nicer" it dont affect the performance of the scipt.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (using jQuery):

```
var accepted = [4,7,10,13,16,19];

if ($.inArray(Size, accepted) != -1)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery

```
var arr = [4,7,10,13,16,19];
if($.inArray(Size , arr)>-1) {
  alert("Yes!")
}
```

Vanilla js

```
var arr = [4,7,10,13,16,19];
if(arr.indexOf(Size)>-1)
{
 alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((Size - 1)%3 == 0 && Size>=4 && Size<=19) alert("Yes!");
```

Comment: because the min in the if is 4 and the max is 19

Comment: in this case use only the first element of the if

Answer (score 0):

The set `{ 4, 7, 10, 13, ... }` can also be described as `{ x | ∃ k ∈ ℕ⁺ : x = 3 k + 1 }`, which can be rearranged to `{ x | ∃ k ∈ ℕ⁺ : k = (x - 1) / 3 }`.

So all you have to check is if `(Size - 1) / 3` is a positive integer. Or, put it another way, if `Size - 1` is positive AND a multiple of 3:

```
(0 < Size - 1) && ((Size - 1) % 3 === 0)
```

But again each subexpression can be rearranged without changing its meaning, by adding 1 to both sides:

```
(1 < Size) && (Size % 3 === 1)
```

And because the first number that fits this expression is `Size === 4`, we can even substitute `1 < Size` with `4 <= Size`. This makes the code more clear and more efficient.

So in its final form the code could be written like this:

```
if (4 <= Size && Size % 3 === 1) {
    alert("Yes!");
}
```